# Workflow when using HG Subversion to push to SVN

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

This question is very similar to the one posed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503152/mercurial-to-mercurial-to-subversion-workflow-problem) question, but I'm having some issues following the workaround.

**The Problem:**

Basically I have a subversion server and a mercurial local client. The extension hg-subversion allows mercurial to act as a subversion client. This is ideal for me because I can make unlimited feature branches off my subversion development branch and merge them in as I choose fit.

Due to a limitation of subversion, I cannot commit a branch merge to a subversion repository. In fact, I don't need to commit every branch merge, I just want the "default" branch head to be committed to SVN.

**The Proposed Solution:**

A workaround user Harvey recommended was to modify my workflow to include an hg-only clone of a hgsubversion clone for development.

To quote Harvey:

> The trick is to learn the modified hg<->hgsubversion<->svn workflow. Once you "get" how it works, you won't have any trouble. You'll just type a few more commands. I've actually started writing scripts to make the process (which is repetitive) easier. Typical flow: [in "hg" repo] commit a bunch of changes; push them to "hgsubversion"; [switch to "hgsubversion"] hg update (hgsubversion needs this); hg push to "svn" (which automatically re-pulls after you push and removes your changesets locally); [switch back to "hg"] hg pull from "hgsubversion"; hg strip the older duplicates b/c "hg" isn't an hgsubversion clone and doesn't know to automatically strip the old changesets.

**The Issue I'm Running Into:**

I'm getting stuck at the point where I run hg push from hgsubversion to the svn repository. I'm still getting the error message, "abort: Sorry, can't find svn parent of a merge revision."

Admittedly I'm not 100% on how hgsubversion pushes revisions to svn. Honestly I'd like to see the state my local copy is in pushed to the svn server.

Halp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have decided to answer my own question for archival purposes (and for those having the same issue).

I found [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992306/submitting-hg-changes-back-to-svn) where the answer was simply stated, you can't do it. Please refer to the above link and up-vote Eric-Karl's answer if this was helpful to you. He does offer a work-around to recover.

Answer (score -1):

### Using HgSubversion knowledge

If I understand the question correctly, hgsubversion will only push to your current revision.

e.g. if you've done 10,11,12,and then merged a 13 from a dev branch. You can

```
hg up 12
hg push
```

Due to the way it'll do the rebases etc, you'll end up pushing to 12 and then being updated to 13, but it works for me.

### New hg functionality

Use the [mercurial phases](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Phases) and mark the revisions you don't want to push as secret.  Of course this will prevent you from pushing to other repositories as well.

### Use corporate policy

The other nice situation at our work is that all code commits must have a reviewer and issue. If something is not intended for svn (but is in our team/spike repository), then I don't put that information in and any accidents are stopped by a pre-commit hook failure.